# Using SinkVITA49 and SourceVITA49

Tags: redhawksdr

This is using Redhawk 1.1.0 on CentOS 6.7.

I'm attempting to set up a very simple example using `SinkVITA49` and `SourceVITA49` blocks using the RedHawk IDE, just in the Chalkboard area. There are 3 blocks involved: a `whitenoise` block, a `SinkVITA49` block, and a `SourceVITA49` block. The connections are:

```
whitenoise dataFloatOut -> SinkVITA49 dataFloat_in
SinkVITA49 dataVITA49_out -> SourceVITA49 dataVITA49_in
```

The network settings of the Sink/Source blocks are left unchanged (so using `127.0.0.1:12344` over UDP).

From this setup, I would expect the values produced by the `whitenoise` block to come out unchanged at the `dataFloat_out` port of the `SourceVITA49` block, however, the values never seem to arrive.

Using the port monitor, I can see the `whitenoise -> dataFloatOut` is sending out data, `SinkVITA49 -> dataFloat_in` is receiving data, however, `SinkVita49 -> dataVITA49_out` does not seem to be transmitting anything, and there is no output at `SourceVITA49 -> dataFloat_out`.

The only property I have changed is under VIAT49Processing_override for the `SourceVITA49` block, specifically the `data_item_format`, which is set to `DataType_Float`.

The console output is (slightly cleaned up):

> WARNING: No leap seconds file found at $VRT_LEAP_SECONDS or $VRTHOME/cpp_lib/tai-utc.dat, using built-in table.
>
> 2015-09-03 16:30:38 INFO  SinkVITA49_i:402 -  ---- TRANSMITTING PACKETS ON 'eth0' AT 127.0.0.1:12344
>
> WARNING: No leap seconds file found at $VRT_LEAP_SECONDS or $VRTHOME/cpp_lib/tai-utc.dat, using built-in table.
>
> 2015-09-03 16:30:41 INFO  SourceVITA49_i:475 -  UNABLE TO CHANGE SCHEDULER AND PRIORITY. CHECK PERMISSIONS....
>
> 2015-09-03 16:30:41 INFO  SourceVITA49_i:608 -  UNABLE TO CHANGE SCHEDULER AND PRIORITY. CHECK PERMISSIONS...140402760169216
>
> 2015-09-03 16:30:41 INFO  SourceVITA49_i:616 -  **** LISTENING FOR PACKETS ON 'eth0' AT 127.0.0.1:12344

Edit: I did a bit of digging with wireshark, and noticed that it is sending
context packets every 1s (the default time between context packets in `advanced_configuration`). Still no data is coming through, however.

Comment: I think you mean REDHAWK 1.10 rather than 1.1.0. Hopefully you're using REDHAWK 1.10.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try the settings from the [VITA49 waveform](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/vita49_loopback_demo/blob/1.0.0/vita49_loopback_demo.sad.xml) delivered with REDHAWK 2.0. Specifically, try using the loopback interface (`lo`) rather than `eth0`.